# SSH Remote Port Forward Host Passwordless

Tags: ssh, password, autossh

I have a Remote Port Forward SSH tunnel from the `host1` the `host0` at port 10022 through:

```
$ autossh -R 10022:localhost:22 host0
```

With `host0` record in the `~/.ssh/config` file both at `host1` and `host0`:

```
# host0
Host host0
    Hostname host0ddnsip
    Port 1022
    User host0user
```

Established from the `host0` to the `host1` through:

```
$ ssh -p 10022 host1user@localhost
```

Which is done passwordless succesfully. The string `host0ddnsip` is the server DNS from a free service (`"host0".dynu.net` hosted by www.dynu.com).

The keys are stored all together in the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` both at `host1` and `host0`:

```
 ssh-rsa AFAF... ...AFAF host0user@host0
 ssh-rsa AFAF... ...AFAF host1user@host1
```

When doing the connection:

```
$ ssh -p 1022 host0user@host0ddnsip
```

It always requests for the password. The same happens with `autossh` going idle some hours at `host1`, turning it useless because it wants a password after that:

```
$ ECDSA host key for IP address 'host0ddnsip' not in list of known hosts.
$ host0user@host0ddnsip's password:
```

Also at `host0` the password is also requested:

```
$ host0user@host0ddnsip's password:
```

How should i make the configuration in this case?

Comment: please, copy and paste to the question the exact outputs you see. Where is the key you are using for passwordless authentication?

Comment: Essentially i've just replaced the strings `host0`, `host1`, `host0user`,  `host1user`, `host0ddnsip`, and the key strings, and all other texts are equal. The only output is the `ECDSA host key....` already pasted in the end of the question, requesting the password.

Comment: Once more: Where are the authentication keys stored in your client? To resolve the question, running the `ssh` command with `-vvv` switches to see a debug log would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok, i will do and update accordingly

Comment: Are you using the right username? You use both `host` and `host0user` in your question. Also you havent provided much needed information, like the sshd_config on the server, etc. The sshd logs would be helpful, so would upping the verbosity (which will print useful information). Likely `ssh -vvv` and the sshd logs will tell you a suitable key was not found.

Comment: Now i had another error, i think not related with this problem :).

Comment: I finally fixed it. The mechanism of the ssh server, involving the key storage was not done through `authorized_keys` file, but through a manual upload. I am using Bitvise SSH server...